# Cannot connect SSRS VM to SQL Azure Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, reporting-services, virtual-machine

I have an SQL Azure database, and have a an Azure CM which is running SSRS.

I can build a report in Visual Studio, and see my data when I preview it.

I can connect to the Azure database from the SQL server management studio on the VM fine.

However, when I deploy the report to the reporting server I get a very generic and unhelpful message of:

**An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Cannot create a connection to data source 'SQLAzure'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
The report server has encountered a configuration error. (rsServerConfigurationError)**

I have added both the public and private IP addresses of the VM to the database firewall rules, and have also opened outbound TCP port 1433 to allow the connection to the database.

Would appreciate any help as to what the cause of this could be.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, but did you manage to get it to work? We have the exact same issue with the exact same setup. In addition the connection is working fine when connecting from a SQL Server Management Studio on the VM itself, hence no firewall or port issues.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149308/how-to-setup-ssrs-with-an-azure-sql-server-database

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is related to the edition of SSRS that has been installed on the VM. If you have a *Web* edition than you won't be able to connect to a SQL Azure database.

This [Reporting Services Feature matrix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc645993.aspx#Reporting) states that only as from the *Standard* edition, you can connect to any SQL Server database, independent of the target edition. If you have a *Web* edition, you'll only be able to connect to a *Web* edition and the SQL Azure database is definitely not running on a *Web* edition, hence the connection will not work.