# How to setup SSRS with an Azure SQL Server Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-reporting

I have a SQL Server Database on Azure Cloud and I want to get a report server up and runnning using SSRS that would accesses the data on that database.

Does anyone have any experience with this scenario, or could provide me some guidance on how to go about this.

I'm reading about how SSRS would run on a Azure VM and that the SQL Server and it's respective Database(s) would be installed on that Azure VM. That's not my situation as I have existing SQL Database that exists outside of any VM I spin up.

Thanks,

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You will need to host SSRS either on an Azure VM or on premise.

In [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20140523110804/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj992719.aspx) deployment topologies for SSRS on Azure VM are discussed.

One strategy is to deploy SSRS to a VM and use Azure SQL Database as the data source.

Once you deploy the VM containing SSRS,  you can then connect SSRS to an Azure SQL DB. This artcle discusses [connecting Azure SQL Database to SSRS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519560.aspx).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you have to pay for a full sql license (rental) on top of the sql azure costs?

Comment: @Sam, If you use one of the SQL Gallery Images, then you don't need an additional SQL Server license. See Azure VM pricing [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/virtual-machines/)

Comment: We have configured a VM[Standard DS2 v2 (2 cores, 7 GB memory)] with SQL Server Enterprise Edition in it. For now, we have stopped the VM (Deallocated). In this case, Do I need to pay for SQL Server?

Comment: which VM Image in Azure contains SSRS?

Comment: Using the VM + Azure SQL DB approach is it possible to use Azure AD for authentication, and avoid Windows Auth when connecting to SSRS?

Answer (score 5):

Another approach to SSRS support for SQL Azure is SQL SSRS containers.   Windocks provides an automated approach that delivers configured SSRS containers for SQL Azure source databases.  The advantage of containers in this case includes updating images, and greater scalability.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct, you'll need to migrate your database to a SQL Server running in an Azure VM. You can use the Azure Export Service (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6899710-634e-425a-969d-8db1267e9471#ExportDB) to export your Azure Database into a dacpac. You can then import the dacpac to the SQL Server VM.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a Azure VM with SQL Server, start up the SSRS Reporting Configuration Manager. Go to SQL Server Management studio on your VM and create a linked server to your existing SQL Database. Create your queries in the VM database to reference the linked server's data. Then create your reports using the database on the VM, but those queries will be pulling the data from your non-VM database.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SSRS not supported by Azure Sql Server.

Comment: That's just a sunset of the SQL Reporting service offered by Azure. There is still support for SSRS on an Azure VM

Comment: Sure, I just thought the original question was in the context not using VM, but using Azure SQL database. Unless I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

Power BI service (premium), now allows you to upload SSRS files, that can connect to the Azure DB. https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/public-preview-of-paginated-reports-in-power-bi-premium-now-available/

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not to have your Azure SQL Database on the Azure VM. All Specify your connection string to point to your Azure SQL Database

Answer (score -1):

SSRS does not support Azure SQL DB for its Catalog and Temp DBs. This is a known issue. You have use to SQL Server (on-prem or Azure VM). You can create and run reports that consume date from Azure SQL DB though.

Comment: Can you comment on why it won't work? If in the Report Server Database Configuration Wizard you provided the correct server name, SQL auth and username/password, why wouldn't the SSRS engine accept databases hosted in Azure SQL Database?

Comment: @LarrySilverman It wont work because the Azure SQL database engine doesn't have the supporting functionality/code required in the instance to make the SSRS tables work