# Can I connect SSRS on an Azure IaaS VM to an Azure App Service and Azure SQL without building an App Service Environment

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services

Is it possible to create a secure connection between an Azure App Service, an Azure SQL database, and SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) hosted on an Azure VM without creating an Azure App Service Environment. We are trying to keep costs to a minimum, and would prefer using normal Azure App Services without having the added expense of maintaining an App Service Environment.

If it is possible, how do we do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yup. We do this exact same thing.

We have web apps running both as Cloud Services as well as App Services (on a ~$50/mo App Service Plan) that primarily consume a SQL Database for the data store. Then we've deployed SSRS to an Azure VM also consuming that same SQL Database. Lastly, we have our web apps consume the SSRS via the web services to pull reports and then re-host them from the web apps themselves. We do not expose our SSRS server to the internet for security reasons but if you wanted to, you could.

There's no reason that I know of that even the **free** App Service Plan couldn't do the same thing with your web app as long as you stayed within its quotas/limits.

Comment: Thanks, Jaxidian. Can you provide additional detail around the implementation and configuration to make this happen?

Comment: There's a lot that goes into that. I'd be happy to answer any specific questions but I simply don't have the time to document the entire process to set everything up - that would likely take many hours to do well. Which parts are unclear to you?

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation that you followed when you set this up? I am assuming you set up a Hybrid Connection in the Networking blade of your App Service. Is my assumption accurate?

Comment: I set this up years ago and I didn't follow any real instructions in doing so. Over the years this was migrated from 100% on-prem to 100% PaaS but when the PaaS offering of SSRS was discontinued I spun up the VM and setup SSRS on it and changed endpoints, a little bit of client code, and now I manage the VM. I'll try to add some additional details to my answer today, maybe that will help you ask more pointed questions. In the meantime, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149308/how-to-setup-ssrs-with-an-azure-sql-server-database