# How to do SSRS report on azure platform as a service

Tags: database, azure, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have planned to do SSRS on azure environment but our client not affordable to buy azure virtual machine. Can we do SSRS report on azure platform as a service (PaaS)?

Answer (score 1):

SSRS is not supported on Azure SQL Database. You must have a virutal machine.
See [how-to-setup-ssrs-with-an-azure-sql-server-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149308/how-to-setup-ssrs-with-an-azure-sql-server-database).

You should have a look on [Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/) : you can make reports with this technology.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SSRS is not available as PaaS on Azure, it is only available by making an Azure VM (IaaS).

If you intend to embed report viewing within a web application (such as by using Report Viewer) you might be able to get away without using SSRS and using 'local reports' instead, which have a very similar syntax to SSRS reports which are hosted on a server.

Power BI might be an alternative worth considering, but there will be a cost to this also if you want to use the reports within apps or shared between users.