# SQL Server Reporting Service (SSRS) on Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, reporting-services, azure-sql-database

Azure SQL Database supports Full recovery model and we can't change the recovery model of Azure SQL Databases.

As mentioned [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/36400585-allow-recovery-model-to-be-changed-to-simple-in-az)
while making report server all application data is stored in reportserver and reportservertempdb.

According to the specific recommendations reportserver follows full recovery model and reportservertempdb follows [simple recovery model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/backup-and-restore-operations-for-reporting-services?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#backing-up-the-report-server-databases).

So is it only the reason that reportservertempdb follows simple recovery model and that is not supported by Azure SQL database we can't configure SSRS on Azure SQL Database or there is something else too.

Please help me out with this with docs or links.

Comment: It's not very clear that what your problem is. Can you clarify it for us?

Comment: Hi @shubhi jain, welcome to stack overflow, we are all glad to help you can response us. If my answer is helpful for you,  plase accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. If you have any other concerns, please feel free to let me know, thank you.

Comment: thank you for the answer and it is helpful for me as it is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Hi Shubhi Jain, what exactly is the issue you were finding? Simply recovery model vs full recovery model? As full recovery model is full featured- that would be fine to configure, would it not? Have you encountered an error when attempting to configure it as full recovery on both databases? I am looking at running hybrid SSRS instance and would like to know if there was any real issue or simply skepticism of functionality. To me, full is better than simple and I would think it should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL single database doesn't support SSRS. And Azure SQL database product team said they have no plan to add it.

You can continue configure the SSRS for Azure SQL managed instance or use if for SQL Server in VMs.

Ref this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/7955331-support-sql-server-reporting-service):
[image]

Comment: No, this is confusing because it makes sense that a DB team would not support running SSRS site, IIS, and all the infrastructure. The question and answer are both poorly written and the link is no longer valid. Another poorly written question remains unanswered from 5 years: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/53567a64-7b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0    yet people say they've done it. What's the issue?

Answer (score -2):

This is a confusing topic because it makes sense that Azure SQL db architecture and development team would not support running SSRS front end and site as it requires IIS, and all the infrastructure. The accepted answer has a link that is no longer valid. The issue is that the question and answer do not specify *what* is and *what is not* supported- is it just the front end? Can the databases be hosted in Azure SQL and front end on a VM? It's not a complete question, or a complete answer. User says they want SSRS on Azure SQL but how was that interpreted and how did the MSFT read that question, and why was the response not detailed at all?

Another poorly written *suggestion* remains unanswered from 5 years ago, and I think it's the reason for the quick undetailed response from MSFT, because they get a lot of these that dont make sense: https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/53567a64-7b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0

As I read it, OP is asking if this can be done in a hybrid method (this is separate completely from expecting SSRS site to run in a database alone), where the front end is on a VM and backend is in Azure SQL. The only limitation found is a recovery model discrepancy. I think that full recovery model might be fine to run. There are other SO post saying it has been done as hybrid deployment:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149308/how-to-setup-ssrs-with-an-azure-sql-server-database#:~:text=You%20can%20set%20up%20a,reference%20the%20linked%20server's%20data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149308/how-to-setup-ssrs-with-an-azure-sql-server-database#:%7E:text=You%20can%20set%20up%20a,reference%20the%20linked%20server%27s%20data).

When we read the differences between simple and full recovery model on a database, full has logging and simple does not. Applying logging where it's not needed does not seem like it would break anything:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recovery-models-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

My answer would be, have you tried it and received an actual error? Try it and see. I'm up against the same problem now and researching before setup. I am checking with my DBA team shortly and may proceed with a hybrid configuration. If I do, I will try to remember to follow up with my result.