# SSRS on Azure SQL Database Why its not supported?

Tags: azure, reporting-services, azure-sql-database

I came across one issue that I cannot create SSRS databases on Azure SQL Database, netiher I can use the migrated databases of report server in the SSRS Config manager, can anyone explain why is this a limitation and something like Managed Instance or Azure SQL VM is needed in this case?

Is there no other way of configuring Azure SQL Database with SSRS?

Comment: did this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29149308/how-to-setup-ssrs-with-an-azure-sql-server-database, can help you ?

Comment: Azure SQL offerings have changed dramatically since that question was asked almost 6 years ago. The branding of the products have changed also.

Comment: Hi @The Man, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @The Man, can you see my answer? do you have any other concerns?

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL database didn't explain why SSRS is not supported in Azure SQL database.

I think the reason the that [Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/azure-sql-iaas-vs-paas-what-is-overview) is PAAS and different between IAAS: Azure MI and SQL server in VMS:
[image]

And for now, there is no way to configure SSRS for Azure SQL database. SQL database product team confirmed this. Ref this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/7955331-support-sql-server-reporting-service):

- "**Thanks for your feedback here. You can do SSRS today in an Azure VM.
  I’m closing this as we have no plans in SQL DB to significantly grow
  it’s scope to SSRS.**"

If you still want to SSRS, you need to choose Azure SQL managed instance or SQL Server in VMs.

HTH.

[image]

Comment: Both Azure SQL Managed Instance and Azure SQL Database are PaaS. But Managed Instance is closer to SQL Server on VM and thus supports SSRS. Azure SQL Database is serverless, does not have versions anymore, and does not support some features, like SSRS apparently.

Azure SQL Database seems to me more like SharePoint Online, where there are no more versions, the application just gets incrementally enhanced. Thus it's as close as you can get to SaaS while remaining PaaS.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can pick a Azure Virtual Machine and then get things done by yourself, from scratch.

Or you can create RDLC and run them inside a web application, using Azure Database as data source.